# Arm image not working(Android Studio) for AVD. No VT-X on CPU

Tags: java, android, android-studio, virtualization

Trying to debug an app and no VT-x on CPU(Core2duo). So Android studio seems to suggest using an x86 image, which I have downloaded(correct API level) and 'with API's' but still  says your CPU doesn't support VT-x.

I have also tried this with ARM images(with API's and correct API level) via the AVD manager, downloaded them, selected them but still doesn't run, still says your CPU doesn't support VT-x.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference I worked it out, on last stage when creating new AVD, before you click finish there is a setting which allows you to choose hardware or software emulation, choose software if no VT on CPU, however it's so slow it's a barely worth it.